# Three JS render array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js, constants

I want to render an array of objects in a three.js scene

My issue is that when I try to render the object three.js returns me this error

```
three.module.js:8589 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined
at Sphere.copy (three.module.js:8589)
at Frustum.intersectsObject (three.module.js:9344)
at projectObject (three.module.js:21975)
at projectObject (three.module.js:22020)
at WebGLRenderer.render (three.module.js:21776)
at render (eval at ./app/components/View/scene.js (1.chunk.js:23),
```

This is the object i'm trying to render

```
const models = {
 cube: [
{
  type: 'cube',
  name: 'cube_1',
  wire: true,
  material: {
    color: 'tomato',
  },
  soma: {
    position: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0
    },
    rotation: {
      x: 45,
      y: 45,
      z: 45
    },
    scale: {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
      z: 1
    },
    size: {
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      depth: 40
    }
  }       
 }
]
```

}

And this is what I do to render it

```
  const { soma, name, type, material, wire } = models.cube[0]
  const widthC = soma.size.width
  const heightC = soma.size.height
  const depthC = soma.size.depth
  window[`wire_${name}`] = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(new THREE.BoxGeometry( widthC, heightC, depthC ));
  window[`wire_mat_${name}`] = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { ...material } );
  window[`model_${name}`] = new THREE.LineSegments( `wire_${name}`,`wire_mat_${name}` )
  scene.add( `model_${name}` );
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are posting a PHP/javascript mixed code snipet. It is a little confusing at first for non PHP users, but it looks like you are passing strings instead of objects in the 2 last lines of the code:

```
window['model_${name}'] = new THREE.LineSegments( 'wire_${name}','wire_mat_${name}' );
scene.add( 'model_${name}' );
```

which should be instead:

```
window['model_${name}'] = new THREE.LineSegments( window['wire_${name}'],window['wire_mat_${name}'] );

scene.add( window['model_${name}'] );
```

Hope it will help you move forward...

Comment: u nailed it! 

Comment: wow, thanks for explaining what this was, been working with three for a while and my mind melted when i saw this snippet

Comment: Is it safe to say that this question has absolutely zero to do with three.js? I can't figure out though is it JS or a PHP question.